# cv.h no such file or directory but there is such a file

Tags: ubuntu, opencv

I tried to run a c++ program by using Kinect and openCV library in my codeblocks. Everything else seems fine expect for I always get a error said:

> /home/maoyi/Documents/practice/practice2.cpp:10:16: fatal error: cv.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

Can anyone tell me that what exactly does it mean by saying no such file or directory there? Coz I am very sure that I have a practice2.cpp file there and I installed 46% of OpenCV Library though. I followed the instructions about how to install a OpenCV2.1.0 tutorial from:

> http://www.samontab.com/web/2010/04/installing-opencv-2-1-in-ubuntu/

I met problems at the "CMAKE ." step and got some hints like this:

> -- Detected version of GNU GCC: 46 (406)
>   -- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
>   --   package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' not found
>   -- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
>   --   package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' not found
>   -- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
>   --   package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' not found
>   -- checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
>   --   package 'libdc1394-2' not found
>   -- checking for module 'libdc1394'
>   --   package 'libdc1394' not found
>   -- checking for module 'libv4l1'
>   --   package 'libv4l1' not found
>   -- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils
>   -- IPP detected: 
>   -- Parsing 'cvconfig.h.cmake'

And I also tried to open my *synaptic package manager* to install all those missing modules manually however I even could not find some of them. (For example gstream-app-0.10) ... So I have no idea if this could cause the "no such a file or diretory" error or something. I am very new to OpenCV so don't be surprised if the problem is very stupid.. 
But anyway I continued the next "make" step and got more desperate hint below. The installation stopped right at 46% and I am mentioned with tons of errors...
So I hope someone can take a look into it and maybe can hint me with some solutions. Thanks a lot!

> [ 45%] Built target opencv_lapack 
>   [ 45%] Building CXX object src/cxcore/CMakeFiles/cxcore_pch_dephelp.dir/cxcore_pch_dephelp.o
>   In file included from /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1826:0,
>                    from /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/src/cxcore/_cxcore.h:51,
>                    from /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/src/cxcore/cxcore_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:177:13: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
>   In file included from /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:2307:0,
>                    from /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1826,
>                    from /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/src/cxcore/_cxcore.h:51,
>                    from /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/src/cxcore/cxcore_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxoperations.hpp:2043:15: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxoperations.hpp:2591:31: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
>   In file included from /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:2308:0,
>                    from /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:1826,
>                    from /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/src/cxcore/_cxcore.h:51,
>                    from /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/src/cxcore/cxcore_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In member function ‘void cv::Mat::locateROI(cv::Size&, cv::Point&) const’:
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:387:5: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:387:5: note: suggested alternatives:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/./bits/c++config.h:156:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
>   /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/./bits/c++config.h:156:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:387:15: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘delta1’
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:389:9: error: ‘delta1’ was not declared in this scope
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:398:31: error: ‘delta2’ was not declared in this scope
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In member function ‘cv::Point cv::MatConstIterator_<_Tp>::pos() const’:
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3459:9: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3459:9: note: suggested alternatives:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/./bits/c++config.h:156:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
>   /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/./bits/c++config.h:156:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3459:19: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ofs’
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3460:23: error: ‘ofs’ was not declared in this scope
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3460:66: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘y’
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3465:9: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3465:9: note: suggested alternatives:
>   /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/./bits/c++config.h:156:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
>   /usr/include/c++/4.6/i686-linux-gnu/./bits/c++config.h:156:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3465:19: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘ofs’
>   /home/maoyihuang/Downloads/OpenCV-2.1.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3466:23: error: ‘ofs’ was not declared in this scope
>   make[2]: *** [src/cxcore/CMakeFiles/cxcore_pch_dephelp.dir/cxcore_pch_dephelp.o] Error 1
>   make[1]: *** [src/cxcore/CMakeFiles/cxcore_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do for You, is to use ccmake (package cmake-curses-gui). It makes cmake usage easier. Second, You shouldn't even try to compile as long as cmake reports errors.  Try to use package manager with a gui to install missing libraries. Use only the library name for the search, because version may vary. Most of libraries are listed on opencv webpage in section for instalation from source on linux. There is also the easy way. Install opencv from repositories using package manager.